# Mask functions in shared Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps

I want to be able to hide an IMPORTRANGE function on a view-only shared google spreadsheet. In other words, I want the function to run, but I don't want the user to see the function itself Is there anyway to do this?

**Context**: I'm trying to make a grade book and allow students to only see their own row. I have a master sheet with everyone and have individual spreadsheets for each students by importing the header row into A1 and their personal row to A2. They can't edit the contents, but they can still just copy the master URL and see it.

Comment: If you want to hide this function , you can use a Script for them individual spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke too soon when I posted this question. It is a non issue as permission only applies to the particular sheet. A user would need to request access if they pasted the URL into another sheet.

See this [Google Product Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/S9mkwmDbHiU/6cQ6MlHq-dEJ) on permission grandfathering